# Datatable editable - make cell editable based on a condition

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatable

I am using Jquery Datatable Editable. I wanted to know if it is possible to make a cell editable based on a condition.

For example if my data is rendered this way,

### Key     text

1   Help

2   Choice

3   Edit

Key and Text are 2 columns, I want to make the cell with value choice only editable and the cells with value Help and Edit remain readonly. Is it possible to achieve this via Datatable editable ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use jEditable js to make a particular class editable. [Click HERE](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).